# How to exclude info,warning from Jboss7 server.log file

Tags: logging, jboss7.x

I am using jboss-as-7.1.1.Final. While deploying the application, too many info lines are getting logged in the server.log file. How to avoid this?

This is the command i am using to start the server:

```
standalone.bat -b "machine-name"-c standalone-full-ha.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what messages you want to exclude, but have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+To#HowTo-HowtoinCLI%3A).

Using CLI or the web console to change the root logging level or exclude specific categories is your best option.